# Drawing dots in polar

Tags: matplotlib

how to draw just dot in polar coordinates, cannot find any example like that?

When I choose theta and some radius nothing gets displayed, other graphs works perfect.

Comment: Can you show an example of a line of code that produces "nothing"?

Comment: Plenty of examples of matplotlib plots such as http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html in the gallery on the matplotlib website.